# Average integers in field; not row entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like SQL to add numbers from two columns and put the Average of the two numbers in a separate column.

I'm currently using `AVG` this way:

```
AVG(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageCount,
AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageAmount,
```

I would like SQL to give me an average of the `InpCount + OutCount` and put that average in the `AverageCount` column seen above. If I could do this to the `InpAmount + InpCount` field too, then I'm finished.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT M.ProcedureID, 
       M.SegmentDateTime,
       M.PriceID,
       L.DrugID,
       L.NdcDinNumber,
       L.Name,
       M.DeptCorporation,
       M.InpAmount,
       M.InpCount,
       M.OutAmount,
       M.OutCount,

       SUM(InpCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as INtotal,
       SUM(InpAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as  IN$Total,
       SUM(OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as OUTtotal,
       SUM(OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as  OUT$Total,
       SUM(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as TotalCount,
       SUM(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as TotalAmount,
       AVG(InpCount + OutCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageCount,
       AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProcedureID) as AverageAmount,
       row_number() over (partition by ProcedureID order by (select NULL)) as SeqNum

FROM BarRevenueByProcedurePriceInfo M LEFT JOIN
     DPhaDrugData L
     ON M.ProcedureID = L.BillNumber
WHERE DeptID = '010.4730' AND SegmentDateTime = '2013-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND
      (M.InpCount > '0' or M.OutCount > '0') AND DrugID = 'LIDO5GEL4'
```

Comment: Why all the OVER clauses?  Are you trying to show group by procedure id details matched to row data?  What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should calculate the average explicitly. Avg is meant to calculate the average across different records, not across different columns.

Probably you would want to use `SUM(InpAmount + OutAmount) / 2` instead of `AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount)` and similarly `SUM(InpCount + OutCount) / 2` instead of `AVG(InpAmount + OutAmount)`.

Comment: That would work well for the rows where only 2 procedureIDs match. I would probably need an integer to account for a variable amount of rows based on ProcedureID

Comment: @YepItsMe I understood your question so that you wanted to calculate the average of `SUM(InpCount)` and `SUM(OutCount)` for each row of the result set, i. e. calculate an average within each row, and not across rows. If that is not the case, please edit your question to state more clearly what you want to achieve.